# Why won't this return "yes" for two words that are anagrams?

Tags: java

EDIT: I now see count wasn't working. I updated the code so now if count is greater than or equal to either word, it'll return "yes". I'm assuming that's the only fix I need to make, so thank you!

When provided with two input phrases, it should check if the letters of one word are all found in the other word, regardless of capitalization. For example, cat and cat would work, as would cat and catt, dogged and do, etc. My code works for some inputs and not others and I can't figure out why. I tried the inputs "cat" and "cat and it works but "moo" and "moo" don't work. I'm also assuming using `count` might be part of the problem. I also tried using arrays but I figured this might be simpler. I'm not looking for an answer, just an explanation as to why my code is not printing what it should.

Here are my two classes:

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class SuperAnTester{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Enter two words: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String phraseone = scan.nextLine();
        String phrasetwo = scan.nextLine();
        SuperAnagram x = new SuperAnagram(phraseone, phrasetwo);
        x.superAn();
    }}

    public class SuperAnagram{
    private String firstWord;
    private String secondWord;

    public SuperAnagram(String first, String second){
        firstWord = first;
        secondWord = second;
    }

    public void superAn(){
        int count = 0;
        firstWord.toLowerCase();
        secondWord.toLowerCase();

        for (int n = 0; n < firstWord.length(); n++){
            for (int x = 0; x < secondWord.length(); x++){
                if (firstWord.charAt(n) == secondWord.charAt(x)){
                    count++;
                }}}

        if (count >= firstWord.length() || count >= secondWord.length()){
            System.out.println("Yes");
        } else{
            System.out.println("No");
        }}}
```

Comment: Could I use firstword.contains(secondWord) or something like that?

Comment: You are not supposed to remove your question ...

Comment: Sorry, I figured that was the easiest way to stop the replies because I understand where I went wrong.

Comment: And don't forget to validate the answer that helped you for next users. That's the purpose of this website.

Comment: You should have marked one of the answer as "Accepted". SO is a place where everybody learns from anybody's problems. What if someone gets the same problem and searched for it. He is not supposed to post a new question for the same problem, he supposed to learn from this only.

Answer (score 3):

May be the problem is here

```
    firstWord.toLowerCase();
    secondWord.toLowerCase();
```

Change it into

```
    firstWord=firstWord.toLowerCase();
    secondWord=secondWord.toLowerCase();
```

`String` is immutable class. You have to assign it back to a string to reflect the changes.

Comment: This solution is correct, `firstWord.toLowerCase()` has no side effects on the object `firstWord` (and likewise for `secondWord`).

Comment: Yes I know. I have read others post also. I think now OP has found an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward.

If you take for example 'do' and 'doott' for the letter 'd' count will be incremented once (with the first d of doott), for the letter 'o' it will be incremented twice (withe the first and second o of doott).

So count will be equal to 3 and neither do and doott length is equal to that.

What you can do is use `StringUtils.countMatches(yourString, yourchar);` for the two strings and check that for the first one the number is lower or equal to the second.

Comment: OH so the count is just counting double letters multiple times?

Comment: Yes that's it. so you must check that

Answer (score 0):

This code will not work because what if you have `cat` and `caate` ?

```
c == c OK count = 1
...
a == a OK count = 2
...
a == a OK count = 3
...
t == t OK count = 4
```

so at the end count = 4;

count != to 3 (cat) and count != 5 (caate)

So you have to take into consideration the redundant characters

---

The other mistake is that you made the string lower case but you didn't save it. So just assign firstWord.toLowerCase(); to firstWord and secondWord.toLowerCase(); to secondWord.

```
firstWord = firstWord.toLowerCase();
secondWord = secondWord.toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example a bit a confusing to me. I don't think dog and dogg are usually considered anagram? I believe a prerequisite to be anagram, is that both words should have the same number of character.
Please find an example (assuming you only have ascii characters):

```
private static boolean isAnagram(String a, String b) {
    if (a == null || b == null || a.length() != b.length()) return false;

    byte charCount[] = new byte[256];

    a = a.toLowerCase();
    b = b.toLowerCase();

    for (int i = 0 ; i < a.length() ; ++i) {
        charCount[a.charAt(i)]++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < b.length() ; ++i) {
        int current = --charCount[b.charAt(i)];
        if (current < 0) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Based on Wikipedia:

> An anagram is a type of word play, the result of rearranging the
>   letters of a word or phrase to produce a new word or phrase, using all
>   the original letters **exactly once**; for example orchestra can be
>   rearranged into carthorse.

Comment: Yes anagram is not the good word for what this user try to test.